# I'm getting error in @OneToMany hibernate mapping?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, annotations, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to have one to many connection between two classes but im getting this error `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany`.

here is my code,

Job.java

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)

private Set<JobCostSplit> jobCostSplit;
```

JobCostSplit.java

```
@Column(name = "job_id")
private Long jobId;

@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "job_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Job job;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You annotate your `Job` with `@OneToMany`. Means you will have one attribute on `Job` and more on `JobCostSplit`.

So if you want to have one `Job` and more `JobCostSplit` you have to set it like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "job_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Job job;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to annotate  the field in JobCostSplit as @ManyToOne

```
 @ManyToOne
 private Job job
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need to write

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "job")
private Set<JobCostSplit> jobCostSplit= new HashSet<JobCostSplit>();
```

in Job.java ,then add

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="jobId",nullable=false)
private Job job;
```

in JobCostSplit.java

Answer (score 0):

In job.java  replace @OneToMany with @ManyToOne